# Derivative Character Limit in R?

Tags: r

I have a very long expression that I need to take the derivative of:

```
D(expression(-4750000+(((14400*(((x/25)*1)-7.2))+(0*((x*1.05)-7.2))+(144*
((x*0.6)-7.2))*30.41667)-2500)/((0.1+1)^((1-0.5)/12))+(((13216.5802942644*
(((x/25)*1)-7.2))+(0*((x*1.05)-7.2))+(132.165802942644*
((x*0.6)-7.2))*30.41667)-2500)/((0.1+1)^((2-0.5)/12))+.........),'x')
```

When the expression is less than 4000 characters I get a solution.  When it is more than 4000 characters, R gives me a newline and +, expecting more input. I haven't been able to find documentation on a character limit.  Does anyone know why this might be?  Any workarounds or alternatives to finding this derivative? The final character length will be at least 50k.

Comment: "final character length will be at least 50k" - really? I see * 0 and * 1 and expressions that could be simplified...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably seeing an effect of input through stdin which uses the OS newline function. Try putting it in a text file and source()-ing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It's working now.  Do you know if there is a way to do this without doing file IO?  This calculation is done thousands of times.

Comment: As I understand the input of expressions, it is not a limitation of R internals except to the extent the authors chose to use tools from the OS imposed that imposed limits. This is the sort of thing discussed from time to time on R-devel Mailing List.